# Using record value as Twig function parameter

Tags: php, twig, bolt-cms

I'm working on writing a Bolt extension to parse an XML file and return the deserialised object tree for the XML. The parsing and deserialising is working like a charm but I cannot get the filename from the page record working as a parameter for the Twig function.

Extension code (simplified) is:

```
class CompetitionExtension extends SimpleExtension
{
    protected function registerTwigFunctions()
    {
        return [
            'competition' => 'competitionFunction',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Load and parse the competition XML.
     *
     * @param string $filename
     * @return Competition
     */
    public function competitionFunction(string $filename) : Competition
    {
        $competition = null;
        $loader = new FileLoader($filename);
        if ($loader->openFile()) {
            $competition = $loader->parse();
        }
        return $competition;
    }
}
```

The `contenttype` (extended the `homepage`) addition is:

```
competitionxml:
    type: file
    upload: competitions
    group: content
```

Upload of the file is also no problem but the following Twig template code gives an error:

```
{% set xmlfile = homepage.competitionxml %}
{% set comp = competition(xmlfile) %}
```

Using `dump` I see that `xmlfile` has the correct value. But I get the following error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Undefined variable: filename") in "index.twig" at line 27.
```

So how can I use the filename of the attachment as parameter for the Twig function?

Comment: where is your `"index.twig" at line 27`?

Comment: this is the `{% set comp = competition(xmlfile) %}` line.